# SMTP Server Login Failure for smtplib

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I've written a function to text a verizon cell phone from a gmail account, and I'm having issues logging in to the smtp server. The function looks like:

```
def _text(fromwhom,number,text):
    """
    A private function which sends an SMS message to a cell phone number.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fromwhom : string
        The email address sending the alert: "testing@gmail.com"
    number : string
        The user-provided cell phone receiving the job alert.
    text : string
        The content of the job alert.
    """

    server = smtplib.SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587 )
    server.starttls()
    server.login(account_email, account_pw)
    server.sendmail( '{}'.format(fromwhom), '{}@vtext.com'.format(number), '{}'.format(text) )
    server.quit()
```

Does anyone have any ideas about why this is failing? I've tried this with a number of emails and passwords (all to accounts I actually own), and it fails every time. Is this happening on Google's end?

Answer (score 0):

By default，the POP3/IMAP/SMTP server of gmail are not accessible.If you want to use them,you must open them manually.